# Expand Pandas DF Column of a list of dictionaries into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas df that looks like:

[image]

The column 'poolData' is a list of dictionaries, here is an example of what that column looks like:

[image]

I need to map the dictionary so that each value in 'PoolType' becomes a separate column with the 'Amount' value as the value for that cell.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

| id_horse | Win | Place | Show |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21245 | 458.00 | 96.00 | 36.00 |
| 12330 | 673.00 | 287.00 | 205.00 |
| 15860 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 15620 | 89.00 | 287.00 | 36.00 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with apply. In this example, I separate the fields and convert them to float.

```py
data = [{"col": [{"PoolType": "WIN", "Amount": "458.00", "FactionalOdds": "2-1", "Dollar": "6.60"},
       {"PoolType": "PLACE", "Amount": "458.00", "FactionalOdds": "2-1", "Dollar": "6.60"},
       {"PoolType": "SHOW", "Amount": "458.00", "FactionalOdds": "2-1", "Dollar": "6.60"}]},
{"col": [{"PoolType": "WIN", "Amount": "458.00", "FactionalOdds": "2-1", "Dollar": "6.60"},
       {"PoolType": "PLACE", "Amount": "458.00", "FactionalOdds": "2-1", "Dollar": "6.60"},
       {"PoolType": "SHOW", "Amount": "458.00", "FactionalOdds": "2-1", "Dollar": "6.60"}]}]


def separate_column(row):
    for e in row["col"]:
        row[e["PoolType"]] = float(e["Amount"])
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["WIN"] = None
df["PLACE"] = None
df["SHOW"] = None
df = df.apply(separate_column,axis=1)
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed. Thank you!